# WordPress: Can you programmatically create page templates?

Tags: wordpress

I am currently building a React/Redux theme for WordPress using the WordPress API. I need to add Page Templates to my theme. I can do this by creating almost empty files like:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: My Template */
?>
```

But I would like to create these 'Page Templates' programmatically.

The functionality I required is to be able to select a 'Page Template' inside the WordPress CMS and have this come down on the API. This functions as expected if the 'Page Templates' are created as above.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `theme_page_templates` filter.

```
CONST CUSTOM_PAGE_TEMPLATES = array(
  array('slug' => 'home', 'label' => 'Home'),
  array('slug' => 'content-page', 'label' => 'Content Page'),
  array('slug' => 'ordering', 'label' => 'Ordering'),
  array('slug' => 'reviews', 'label' => 'Reviews')
); 

/**
 * Add file-less page templates to the page template dropdown 
 */
add_filter('theme_page_templates', function($page_templates, $wp_theme, $post) {
  foreach(CUSTOM_PAGE_TEMPLATES as $template) {
    // Append if it doesn't already exists
    if (!isset($page_templates[$template['slug']])) {
      $page_templates[$template['slug']] = $template['label'];
    }
  }
  return $page_templates;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```